# MongoDB regex query from Spring Boot

Tags: regex, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to keep a regex in MongoDB document like

```
regexToApply : "someRegularExpression"
```

and I want to query with a string and get all matching documents from mongo.

I played with $regex, but it's not regular regex operation.It's kind of reverse regex operation. I tried to something like below, but it does not return any document.

```
@Query("{$where: ?0.$match('regexToApply')}")
List findByRegex(String myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) with [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html#regexmatch-aggregation)

`{$expr: {$regexMatch:{input:"string", regex:"$regexToApply"}}}`